# serving non-expiring content through Nginx and SEO optimization

Tags: django, caching, nginx, seo

I am serving my content through Apache and Nginx in Webfaction. Webfaction only supports 'epxires_max' directive for its Nginx server for all the static content (images, css files, js, etc).

I tried Google [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) Tool and it says this:

> The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime.
>   Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the
>   following resources:

and then lists about 50 images that it considers I need to specify their expiration.

So my questions are:

(a) Serving content through (Apache and) Nginx (no expires_max directive included) and using memcached, do I also *need* to specify more expire information for my static content?

(b) Apart from 'expires_max' do I have other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically expire information is specified through the use of http headers, specifcally some combination of `Expires`, `Cache-Control`, and possibly `Etag` and `` `Last-Modified ``. See for instance http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/ for some more info on how caching works and what the headers mean.

Setting up those headers is typically something you do in the webserver configuration:

- For Apache you can either add the necessary config to your main apache config (if you have acces to that), or via .htaccess files. What directives you can add in those .htaccess files depends on how the [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive is configured in the main config.
- Nginx requires access to to main server config files, there not being a mechanism similar to .htaccess (see http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess for why)

In other words you need to contact webfaction support (if it's not in their faq) and find out what options are open to you:

- Can you add stuff to the main config yourself? (I gathered no from the comments on Matt's answer)
- Are they willing to add config bits to the config of your virtual host if requested through a ticket?
- What is Apache's AllowOverride set to? and consequently what can you set yourself? (see apache docs linked above)

Comment: Thank you. That was very informative, indeed. But do I actually need to do that? Is it necessary? Will it make my site faster? Aren't memcached+Nginx enough?

Comment: You don't _need_ to do it (your site will work without it), but your definately _want_ it (as it will decrease latency, thus make your site feel faster). Basically setting up cache headers allows proxies and browsercaches to save those resources locally, which means that on 2nd access it's way faster (due to network latency being eliminated), also that means they're not using your server bandwith to request the same thing multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using NGINX to serve all of your static content then adding this within the server block should do the trick:

```
location ~* \.(?:css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where is the "server block"? I am serving through Webfaction and although I suppose you mean some .conf file, are you sure I might have access to it?

Comment: https://www.webfaction.com/ lists 'full shell access' as a feature. so likely you should have access to the conffile. Most likely it's in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` (usually has 1 config file per site)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately Nginx is a system-wide installation and I can't configure my own settings. I am allowed, however, to install my own copy, but I don't have time to that. Anyway, Matt's answer is not answering my question (although it is a nice thing to know).

Comment: Ah I see. Not sure how Webfaction work, but if you don't have complete control over the web server they'll always have the final word in what HTTP headers to strip out and what ones to leave. Good luck anyway, and installing NGINX is a piece of cake. :-)

Comment: jpe?g didn't pickup jpg for me - but your answer helped me work out that "jpeg|jpg" does get both...might be my server options?